# in html page, file uploader accept only png

Tags: jquery, html, css, jpeg

I am developing an app :
I have a file upload input :

```
 <input id="full_demo" type="hidden" name="test[image]">
```

I want to allow .jpg format only ,
is there any method by which i can resolve it.

in my code the file type="hidden" if i'll use type="file" then the cropper plugin will stop working.

i have tried this code but not working :

```
<input type="file" name="pic1" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not jpg its jpeg.

```
<input type="file" name="pic1" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

Comment: i cant change type="file" from type="hidden" as i am using cropper plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
<input type="file" name="pic1" id="image" accept="image/jpeg" />
```

You can also give multiple formats like this.

```
<input type="file" name="pic1" id="image" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />
```

Comment: i cant change type="file" from type="hidden" as i am using cropper plugin

Comment: which cropper plugin you are using ? ?

Comment: and ya , http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

this is the best cropper plugin i have ever seen , hope this helps you .

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

Note that this only provides a hint to the browser as to what file-types to display to the user, but this can be easily circumvented, so you should always validate the uploaded file on the server also.

It should work in IE 10+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari 6+, Opera 15+, but support is very sketchy on mobiles (as of 2015) and by some reports this may actually prevent some mobile browsers from uploading anything at all, so be sure to test your target platforms well.

For detailed browser support, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept

Comment: i cant change type="file" from type="hidden" as i am using cropper plugin